# 2 mysql queries in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to learn PDO and I've not come across this yet on any other sites,

I have 2 queries...

```
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (oauth_provider, oauth_uid, username,email,twitter_oauth_token,twitter_oauth_token_secret) VALUES ('$oauth_provider', $uid, '$username','$email','','')") or die(mysql_error()); 
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE oauth_uid = '$uid' and oauth_provider = '$oauth_provider'");
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        return $result;
```

How is this written as a prepared statement?

```
 $query1 = "INSERT QUERY";
    $stmt1  = $DBH->prepare($query1);

$query2 = "SELECT QUERY";
    $stmt2  = $DBH->prepare($query2);
```

Comment: You are assigning the two statements to the same variable

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is a little confusing, as you are simply overwriting `$query` and only running a single query.

I think you approach to using PDO prepared statements is largely correct, however I would point out that you may consider using different variable names for the statment object if you need to work with them both simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
<?php
try {
      $username = 'user';
      $password = '';
      $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      //1-st request - simplified
      $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` (oauth_provider) 
          VALUES (:oauth_provider)');
      $stmt->execute(array("oauth_provider" => $oauth_provider));

      //2-nd request
      $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` 
          WHERE oauth_uid =:uid AND oauth_provider = :oauth_provider');
      $stmt->execute(array("uid" => $uid, "oauth_provider" => $oauth_provider));
      while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            var_dump($row);
      }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I think, it's obvious, how to use prepared statements:

1. You run `$conn->prepare` and put the SQL request there with `:var_name` for every parameter.
2. You run execute, passing array("var_name" => $var_value) to it.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table1");
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT FROM table2");

$stmt->execute();
$stmt2->execute();
```

It's not a clean solution but it works for me and I'll use it until I can find out an 'elegant' solution.

Make sure to surround it on a try catch block.